# Create summary statistics based on condition

Tags: r

Normally to make summary statistics on a condition I would say

```
summary(data$how_fast[data$weight == 'Medium' & data$height == 'High'], basic = T)
```

But what I would like is to output all of the summary statistics for every variable.

```
summary(data[data$weight == 'Medium' & data$height == 'High'], basic = T)
```

So we'd get summary statistics not just for `$how_fast`, but also for other variable like `$start_speed` or `$medals`.

Ideally, it'd be stored in a awesome table (although I believe you can do this using `rtf package`).

Comment: Use a comma followed by the columns you want, like `summary(data[data$weight == 'Medium' & data$height == 'High', c("how_fast", "start_speed")], basic = T)`

Comment: Wonderful - as an extension  use `variables <- ls(data)` to output all of them.

Comment: I haven't seen the approach you mention in your comment before. To apply it to all columns, I would just put the comma followed by a blank (instead of enumerating the columns): `summary(data[data$weight == 'Medium' & data$height == 'High', ], basic = T)`

Answer (score 0):

`by` lets you apply functions to data frames. The output is an array with dimensionality based on your grouping.

```
dat <- data.frame(A = rep(1:2, each = 10), 
    B = rep(1:2, times = 10), C = rpois(20, 1))
by(data = dat, INDICES = dat[c("A", "B")], FUN = summary, basic = TRUE)
# A: 1
# B: 1
#        A           B           C      
#  Min.   :1   Min.   :1   Min.   :0.0  
#  1st Qu.:1   1st Qu.:1   1st Qu.:0.0  
#  Median :1   Median :1   Median :0.0  
#  Mean   :1   Mean   :1   Mean   :0.6  
#  3rd Qu.:1   3rd Qu.:1   3rd Qu.:1.0  
#  Max.   :1   Max.   :1   Max.   :2.0  
# ------------------------------------------------------------- 
# ...
```

This lets you summarize for all groupings in a data.frame. To just apply for a single subset you could use `lapply`.

```
lapply(X = dat[dat$A == 1 && dat$B == 1, ], 
    FUN = summary, basic = TRUE)
# $A
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#     1.0     1.0     1.5     1.5     2.0     2.0 
#
# $B
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#     1.0     1.0     1.5     1.5     2.0     2.0 
#
# $C
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#     0.0     0.0     1.0     0.9     1.0     3.0
```